# How to check if an Angular object returns type never?

Tags: angular, types, error-handling

I have a frontend application built with Angular 7 (angular/core 7.2.1).
I am building a form with some dinamically loaded HTML selects. When user clicks on a option of first select, this value is used to populate the second select and so on.

I got to HTML selects work, but application is unstable. Each time I reload it with `ng serve`, it fails to compile, presenting a error "`Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'`". This errors is related to value of selected option. In fact, when application is starting, there is no selected option. I can bypass this problem replacing HTML select object with a string and after application is loaded, I change it again to object, and so the application is compiled. But if I stop the angular server and restart it, the error returns.

These are the selects that I want to handle. When user clicks on a option of systemsSelect, a method populates environmentsSelect. When user clicks on a option of environmentsSelect, podsSelect is populated.

```html
<p>
    System: 
    <select [formControl]="systemsSelect"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedSystemOption">
        <option *ngFor="let system of systems" [ngValue]="system"
            (click)="loadEnvironmentsBySystem($event)">{{ system.name }}</option>
    </select> Environment: <select [formControl]="environmentsSelect"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedEnvironmentOption" (click)="loadPods($event)">
        <option *ngFor=" let environment of
        ambientes" [ngValue]="environment">
            {{ environment }}</option>
    </select> Pods: <select [formControl]="podsSelect"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedPodOption">
        <option *ngFor="let pod of pods" [ngValue]="pod">{{ pod }}</option>
    </select>

</p>
```

The component that handles page above is this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-systems-select',
  templateUrl: './systems-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./systems-select.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class SystemsSelectComponent {
  systemsSelect = new FormControl('');
  environmentsSelect = new FormControl('');
  podsSelect = new FormControl('');
  selectedSystemOption: string;
  selectedEnvironmentOption: string;
  selectedPodOption: string;
  systems = [];
  environments = [];
  pods = [];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
      this.loadSystems(undefined);
  }

  loadSystems(event: any) {
      this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8000/system').subscribe(systems => {
          this.systems = systems as any;
      }           
    );
  }

  loadEnvironmentsBySystem(event: any) {
      var name = '';
      if (typeof this.selectedSystemOption === 'object'){
          name = this.selectedSystemOption.name;
      } else {
          name = this.selectedSystemOption;
      }
      this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8000/environment/' + nome).subscribe(ambientes => {
          this.environments = environments as any;
      });     
  } 

  loadPods(event: any) {
      var system = this.selectedSystemOption.name;
      var environment = this.selectedEnvironmentOption;
      this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8000/pod/' + system + '-' + environment).subscribe(pods => {
          this.pods = pods as any;
      }           
    );
  }
```

}

The message error is related to this part of component:

```
      if (typeof this.selectedSystemOption === 'object'){
          name = this.selectedSystemOption.name;
      } else {
          name = this.selectedSystemOption;
      }
```

When `ng build` is executed, it presents error inside if. I tried use typeof for checking if `this.selectedSystemOption` is 'never', but it doesn't work. I would like to have a way to detect this type 'never'. The current behaviour is that `this.selectedSystemOption` with type 'never' returns true when is compared to 'object'. Is there an additional condition that I can added to if for avoid that it tries to read property name?

I expect that variable name has a string, that can be empty if none of options is selected or has the value of selected option.

Comment: You declare `selectedSystemOption` as a string. If it's supposed to be something else, change the declaration. 2. A side note, but you have a typo in `*ngFor="let system of system"`.

Comment: Excuse @mbojko, I translated former identifiers to English and forget the 's', but this part is correct, in original source code the right identifier is in plural.

Comment: About declaration of `selectedSystemOption`, @mbojko, I tried to change it to `object`and the error change to ` Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'string'.`